# images in assets folder not loading Im getting a 304 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs, webpack

When Im trying to load this png file from assets folder im getting a 304 error. Im trying to load pictures from assets folder.

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const config = require('./webpack.config.dev');

const app = express();
const compiler = webpack(config);

app.use("/assets", express.static("assets"));


app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
  noInfo: true,
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath
}));

app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }

  console.log('Listening at http://localhost:3000');
});
```

file tree looks like this

```
Project Name
|-- /assets
|-- /dist
|-- /src
`-- server.js
```

How should I approach this problem? Is it a webpack problem or a simple express one. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP 304 is a redirect - not an error. It means it is loading the image from the cache. If you have been making changes try clearing your cache or opening the browser in private browsing mode so it won't load from it. It may have cached an image/location that is invalid still which is why it isn't loading.

Comment: great :) I ran into this exact same thing with webpack/express just last night so it was still fresh on my mind.